# MKMapView viewForAnnotation: returning nil

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I'm trying to remove a pin from a map.  I have an observer on the @"selected" property of the MKPinAnnotationView so I know which object to delete.  When the user taps the trash can icon and a pin is selected, this method gets called:

```
- (IBAction)deleteAnnotationView:(id)sender {
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView viewForAnnotation:self.currentAddress];
    [pinView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selected"];

    [self.mapView removeAnnotation:self.currentAddress];
    [self.map removeLocationsObject:self.currentAddress];
}
```

This method works fine if I do not drag the pin anywhere.  If I drag the pin, my pinView in the above method returns nil, and the MKPinAnnotationView never gets removed from the MKMapView.  I'm not sure why.  Here's the didChangeDragState delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState {
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D draggedCoordinate = view.annotation.coordinate;

        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:draggedCoordinate.latitude longitude:draggedCoordinate.longitude];
        [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            // Check for returned placemarks
            if (placemarks && [placemarks count] > 0) {
                CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

                AddressAnnotation *anAddress = [AddressAnnotation annotationWithPlacemark:topResult inContext:self.managedObjectContext];
                view.annotation = anAddress;
                self.currentAddress = anAddress;
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

In both the didChangeDragState: and deleteAnnotationView: methods, my self.address object has a valid address.  For some reason though, when the pin is dragged, the pinView is nil.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Observing the selected property should be unnecessary since there's the didSelectAnnotationView delegate method and the selectedAnnotations property in MKMapView.  On the drag end, you are replacing the view's annotation -- not sure this is right.  You should instead try updating the view.annotation's properties instead of replacing with an entirely new object.

Comment: Wouldn't I need an observer so I can know when any <MKAnnotation> is not selected?  I am using it basically to enable and disable the trash can button.  I don't want it displayed if no pin is selected on the map.  I thought the only way I would know that is by looking at the @selected property of all the pins on the map.

Comment: @Anna Karenina Your advice to update the current AddressAnnotation instead of creating a new one did the trick.  Can you put that as an answer so I can close this question?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observing an annotation view's `selected` property via KVO should be unnecessary since there's the `didSelectAnnotationView` delegate method and (even better in your case) the `selectedAnnotations` property in `MKMapView`.

Assuming the user taps the trash can *after* selecting a pin, the trash can tap method can get the currently selected annotation through the `selectedAnnotations` property.  For example:

```
if (mapView.selectedAnnotations.count == 0)
{
    //No annotation currently selected
}
else
{
    //The currently selected annotation is the first object in the array...
    id<MKAnnotation> ann = [mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];

    //do something with ann...
}
```

In the above example, there was no need to access the annotation's view, no observer and no need for your own "currentAddress" property.

If instead you want to do some action immediately when an annotation is selected, you can put the code in the `didSelectAnnotationView` delegate method.  There, the annotation selected is `view.annotation`.

Regarding the issue on the drag-end, the current code is completely replacing the view's `annotation`.  I think this is only a good idea when the view is being created or re-used in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method.  In the drag-end method, you should instead try updating the `view.annotation`'s properties instead of replacing with an entirely new object.